# Forbid extra keys in JSON validation

Tags: json, validation, go, struct

I have tried to forbid extra keys during struct validation in Golang, which is defined as -

```
type Test struct {
Test []*string `json:"test" validate:"required,min=1,max=10,unique"`
}
```

But the validation is not restricting the extra keys in the input JSON and it passes the validation, The method which I used was-

```
validationErr := validate.Struct(user).excludes(extra)
```

is there any other way by which we can forbid extra keys during validation?

Comment: It's hard to respond here, which validation library are you using? Example of the JSON that you want to fail, Example of the JSON you want to pass. Please add more details.

Comment: @KarthikNayak I am using go-validator library "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what you are actually trying to do here.   Are you trying to ensure that the input conforms to a JSON schema?

Comment: @GariSingh, as you can see my struct contains a "test" field and I want during the JSON validation is any other field except "test" to be given as input, the validator should restrict that with an error.

Comment: not sure if this library allows this but encoding/json package has the support while decoding the json input in a struct. Check this out https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields .

Comment: could you also add examples as requested in the second part of my comment?

Comment: Given what you want to do, I think the simplest answer is to go with @shubham_asati suggestion and use Go's built-in JSON decoder